# Doctrine query extension filter by related entity of same table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com, dql

I am using API platform on my Symfony project.

I have 3 tables: account / user / account_user

An account can have a parent account.
When i GET /accounts i need to return all the accounts that have an account_user relating them to the current user AND i also need to return the children accounts of those accounts.

I am using : [API platform's extension system](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#custom-doctrine-orm-extension)

This is what my code looks like:

```
$alias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
    $queryBuilder
        ->innerJoin(sprintf('%s.accountUsers', $alias), 'au')
        ->innerJoin(sprintf('%s.parentAccount', $alias), 'pa')
        ->innerJoin(sprintf('%s.accountUsers', 'pa'), 'paau')
        ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
            'au.user = :current_user',
            'paau.user = :current_user'
        ))
        ->setParameter('current_user', $currentUser)
    ;
```

I am sure this is not correct.
I get this error:

> "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 487 near 'paaccountUsers_a2.user': Error: 'paaccountUsers_a2' is not defined."

I could use some help here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work by getting the ids of the parent accounts first in a sub query and then using that in the Where clause for the real query.

Leaving this here so it may help someone:

```
$subQb = clone $queryBuilder;
    $alias = $subQb->getRootAliases()[0];
    $subQb->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.accountUsers', $alias), 'au')
        ->andWhere('au.user = :current_user')
        ->setParameter('current_user', $currentUser);

    $subQuery = $subQb->getQuery();
    $subQuery->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, LimitSubqueryOutputWalker::class);
    $foundIdRows = $subQuery->getScalarResult();
    $ids = array_map('current', $foundIdRows);

    if (empty($ids)) {
        return;
    }

    $alias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
    $queryBuilder->resetDQLPart('where');
    $queryBuilder->setParameters(new ArrayCollection());
    $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.accountUsers', $alias), 'au');
    $queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
        sprintf('%s.parentAccount in (:ids)', $alias),
        'au.user = :current_user'
    ))->setParameter('current_user', $currentUser)
    ->setParameter('ids', $ids);
```